# Searching an expression logic in informatica mappings

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to search an expression code, in multiple informatica mappings with out manually going through the mapping? Say like exporting the mapping into an XML or anything similar.

Example : 
I need to search if we are using an expression where we check if a field is NULL like below :

IF(ISNULL(PORT1), CONDITION1, CONDITION2)

I need to search say N number of mappings to check if i am using ISNULL function anywhere in the mapping, as we are going to replace all the NULL's in the database with default values and setting all the fields to NOT NULL, and in the informatica logic, if we are explicitly checking for ISNULL conditions, we would have to recode the logic.

Basically i need to do impact analysis, and need to check if and where there is an ISNULL condition used, it should be replaced with default values instead. say the above condition looks like below :

IF(PORT1='', CONDITION1, CONDITION2)

Any assistance would extremely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export all workflows from repository manager as a single xml. Then search for the expression. If this is something you need to do frequently, you can consider writing script utility script to do this and return the list of mapping names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect answer. After posting the question, i myself tried that yesterday, and it perfectly works. But thanks so much, it would have helped a lot if i was not able to figure it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by exporting the wf into xml and do search and replace using any text editor and then import the wf using repository manager.

If you want to check this is happening under sql override query then use repository query on meta data tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since Samik answered this first, i will mark his answer as the right one. Thanks for the added information that if its under an SQL override, then i could query the repository meta data tables.